# Why using Task.Run on async function doesn't return Task<Task<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, return-type

Consider the following code snippet in which the `MyMethod` and its asynchronous version `MyMethodAsync` is called in different ways:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int MyMethod()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            return 42;
        }

        static async Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return 42;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result1 = MyMethod(); // int
            var result2 = MyMethodAsync(); // Task<int>
            var result3 = Task.Run(() => MyMethod()); // Task<int>
            var result4 = Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync()); // Task<int>
        }
    }
}
```

In each case, I have commented the return type.

The question is why the type of `result4` is `Task<int>` too? Shouldn't it be `Task<Task<int>>`?

BTW, is there any case that calling an async method by `Task.Run` could be beneficial?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns a `Task<int>` is that you're calling the [`Task.Run(Func<Task<TResult>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, which returns a task that serves as a proxy for the task returned by your function. If you wanted to use the original overload, you could specify the generic type parameter:

```
var result3 = Task.Run(() => MyMethod()); // Task<int>
var result4 = Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync()); // Task<int>
var result5 = Task.Run<Task<int>>(() => MyMethodAsync()); // Task<Task<int>>
```

As for your second question: using `Task.Run` on an asynchronous operation is beneficial when the said operation also has a synchronous part, which thereby gets executed on a background thread, rather than blocking your original thread. For example, [`StreamWriter.WriteAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193364(v=vs.110).aspx) might need to serialize the string to a byte array before writing it asynchronously to disk. The serialization is done synchronously, and might benefit from being run on a background thread.